# Multiline menu with CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to create a userfriendly multiple OnePage website.

Normally with a OnePage website you have a menu which contains anchorpoints.
What I want to do now is have a main menu which contains links to 3 seperate OnePages and a submenu which contains the anchorpoints pertaining to the current OnePage.

In other words:
What I would like to do is create 3 pages, these 3 pages should each have their own hyperlinked button in the main menu. When you visit one of these pages you should have a sub-menu below the mainmenu with all anchorpoints in the menu pertaining to that page.

Simple example:
- main menu -
**Home** | Education | Corporate
- sub-menu -
**Start** | About us | Partners | Courses | Contact us

- main menu -
Home | **Education** | Corporate
- sub-menu -
**Start** | Products | Advantages | Our Clients | Contact us

- main menu -
Home | Education | **Corporate**
- sub-menu -
**Start** | Products | Advantages | Our Clients | Contact us

My question is, can you achieve this with CSS in a setup like this?

```
<ul class="primary">
 <li class="page_item">
  <a href="#" class="external active">Home</a>
  <ul class="children">
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="#" class="">Start</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="#" class="">About us</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="# class="">Partners</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="# class="">Courses</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="# class="">Contact us</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="page_item page-item-1522">
  <a href="#" class="external">Education</a>
  <ul class="children">
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="#" class="">Start</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="#" class="">Products</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="# class="">Advantages</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="# class="">Our Clients</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="# class="">Contact us</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="page_item page-item-1522">
  <a href="#" class="external">Corporate</a>
  <ul class="children">
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="#" class="">Start</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="#" class="">Products</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="# class="">Advantages</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="# class="">Our Clients</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item">
    <a href="# class="">Contact us</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want us to google "CSS Dropdown Menu" for you? There are plenty of examples all over the web of CSS dropdown menus.

Comment: I did actually google this, thnx for the offer.

Nope, didn't find any multiline examples.

Comment: It's unclear what CSS has to do with this question. Figure out how you want to set up your html markup first, then you can start working on the CSS. Additionally, "multiple OnePage" sounds like an oxymoron.

Comment: What do you mean by `multiline`?

Comment: Yes it's an oxymoron. I'm stuck with this setup, that's why it's a CSS question: "My question is, can you achieve this with CSS in a setup like this?"

Comment: Multiline as in: two horizontal lines(bars), first one contains/is the main menu, second one contains/is the submenu. I'm using the wrong terms, but I hope you get the picture.

Comment: Yes you can do that. What you want to do is display/hide the submenu based on rollover or click on the main menu.

Comment: :hover doesn't work well on touch, but you can study this CSS and use Super Click (not Super Fish) which has identical css. http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/nav-bar/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue a while back.

In the end I separated the sub-menus out from the main menu, i.e.

```
<h2 class="hidden">Main Menu</h2>
<ul>
    <li class="selected">Home</li>
    <li>Education</li>
</ul>
<h3 class="hidden">Sub Menu</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Start</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    ...etc...
</ul>
```

I would have preferred not to do it this way and instead do what you're suggesting.  However due to the structure of my main navigation I would need to rely on some nasty positioning tricks if each sub-menu was included within the main menu's `<li>` tags, in order to shift everything over to the left-hand edge of the page.

There might be a better way, but one quick and dirty method I came up with just now is as follows:

[CSS]

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

[HTML]

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Education
        <ul>
            <li>Start</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Other</li>
</ul>
```